# Создание своего компонента на Java

Tags: gui, java, компоненты

Здравствуйте.

Написал свой компонент на Java (Поле, на котором будут происходить события в игре):

```
public class Pole extends JPanel
{
    public static int CHECK_SIZE = 40;
    public Check check[][] = new Check[21][21];
    public int cw, ch, width, height,
        focusX = 0, focusY = 0;
    public Game game;
    public MainWindow mw;
    public Pole(int aw, int ah)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
                check[j][i] = new Check();
        cw = aw; ch = ah;
        width = cw * CHECK_SIZE + cw + 1;
        height = ch * CHECK_SIZE + ch + 1;
        setSize(width, height);
        addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
            {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
                {

                }
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
                {

                }
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
                {

                }
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    setFocusPixel(e.getX(), e.getY(), e.getButton());
                    mw.redrawStatePanel();
                    repaint();
                }
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
                {

                }
            });
    }
    /* ... */
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        /* Прорисовка сетки и объктов на ней */
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Но почему-то когда я его добавляю на другую панель, то он либо становиться вообще невидимым, либо виден только кусок моего компонента. А когда я следом за свои компонентом добавляю ещё один, например:

```
add(pole);
add(infoLabel);
```

то следующий появляется где-то на pole, т.е. перекрывает его. Мне кажется, что тут какая-то проблема с размерами компонента, хотя я его указал функцией setSize(width, height).

Кстати если компонент просто добавить на окно, то всё нормально. И если pole добавить так add(pole, BorderLayout.CENTER), а потом добавлять другие компоненты сверху add(infoLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH), то всё в порядке.

Помогите разобраться. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у Вас не указаны начальные размеры для компоненты. Поэтому размер панели определяется контейнером, куда вы ее запихнули, и устанавливается в минимальные значения (в Вашем случае 0, 0). С бордер лаяутом все ОК, потому что в этом лаяут менеджере под центр выделено больше всего места.

**update**  - добавил пример кода:

```
public class DummyFrame extends JFrame
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        // create special panel with defined size
        JPanel comp = new JPanel () ;
        comp.setBackground ( Color.RED ) ;
        comp.setPreferredSize ( new Dimension ( 150, 90 ) ) ;

        // create frame
        SplitDates splitDates = new SplitDates () ;
        splitDates.setSize ( 500, 500 ) ;
        splitDates.setBackground ( Color.BLUE ) ;
        splitDates.setLayout ( new FlowLayout () ) ;
        splitDates.setDefaultCloseOperation ( DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE ) ;

        splitDates.add ( comp ) ;
    }    
}
```

Comment: @jmu, И как же мне указать начальные размеры. Я ведь вроде бы их указал с помощью setSize(width, height)?

Comment: Добавил пример, этого должно быть достаточно чтоб ответить на ваш вопрос